# Gigabyte z68ap-d3 and ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, wireless, 13.04, dual-boot

Basically, I've been trying to install ubuntu to dual boot alongside windows 7. However, I've had strange outcomes.

I first tried to install ubuntu 13.04. After problems with it, I tried ubuntu 12.10, with similar problems.

I seem to have issues with the graphics card and the wireless. More specifically:

- When I loaded the live CD (and after I'd installed) I seem to have two desktops, at first "overlayed" each other (I had two power down icons, wireless buttons... with one screen in the NW of the screen and another "wrapped around" it). I only have one monitor plugged in; on display, one shows up as Samsung 19", which is correct, and the other as "unknown". I don't know what this other display is or why it's there. On ubuntu 13.04, I couldn't remove this problem; I could move the display around so that it wasn't visible but my mouse could move off screen onto it (although of course I couldn't see it). Ubuntu 12.10 was more manageable and has turned off this other display, although it still appears in display settings.
- Perhaps linked to this is that in the details, or about this computer window, it lists my graphics as "unknown".
- My wireless connection, whilst working, tends to operate at terribly low speeds. I have a netbook running ubuntu 13.04 which has no problems like this.

I've also occasionally seen scrambled up orange desktop screens on boot, although this tends to go away after a couple of boots. I had a few times where the live CD failed to boot (I've tried ubuntu 13.04 on a USB and 12.10 on CD). Another thing I'd point out is that in the GRUB loader now, I have two entries for the windows loader and, as well as some memtest options, ubuntu, ubuntu recovery and "older linux versions". Perhaps this points to me incorrectly installing in the first place?

At the moment, ubuntu 12.10 is on my system, and seems to run much more smoothly than 13.04. For the most part, it is completely usable, except for it's horribly slow wireless connection. I worry of course that, with these strange issues, there will be many more lurking around that I can't see yet.

I haven't given you too much information; please tell me what information (hardware, terminal outputs etc.) I should give and how to get it (please bear in mind that I'm totally new to linux). Given that I have several issues, I will note my motherboard: it's a   Gigabyte GA-Z68AP-D3 socket 1155, and that my wireless card is pretty old (windows failed to automatically find drivers for it; I eventually found Ralink RT2500 ones that worked).

I'm sure there are no hardware faults though, since everything runs fine on windows 7.

Thanks

[edit]:

Ok, so I think the problem is the motherboard, which doesn't seem to get on too well with linux.

I tried the following:

http://www.tutonics.com/2012/10/fix-graphics-unknown-in-ubuntu-1210.html#.Ugzfg6wju1G

and now at least my graphics don't know up as "unknown" (although I do still have an extra unknown monitor in displays).

Next I tried to sort out the wireless connection. I followed this:

http://alexravenel.com/gigabyte-ga-z68ap-d3-network-issues-in-ubuntu.html

and the result is that now, instead of having a slow connection, I have no connection; the wireless can't find any networks.

Any help would be much appreciated.